# How to allow the web service to connect the raspberryp server which is linked to router with public IP address

Tags: raspberry-pi, gateway

I have built a node.js server inside the a raspberry PI, and the PI is linked to a router. of course this server in the PI have a local IP address like 192.168.1.130, and the router has a static public IP address. This server can send a IP request to the outside

due to the NAT and gateway in the router, Now I want to know is it possible to allow a web service to connect to this local server.

I remembered I made a local server in my computer, when I input this server 's address to the  facebook 3rd party app. The facebook 's 3rd party app can visit the pages served in the local server.

I think it is feasible, but how to truly do it?

Answer (score 0):

you has to map your PI device on router, in session "map ports"

On router has a table with origin port, and destination host/port

at Origin Port, inform 80
at Destination, inform host 192.168.1.130 port 80

generally, the router allow you to maps a range (ex: 80~90)... but, at two fields, fill with desired port (e.g. 80)